# Sticky cart summary on magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, shopping-cart, sidebar

I want to stick my cart.summary (sidebar) in cart page. mean that, when i scroll down to see other items in cart page, side bar stick in the left and always can see him over scroll up or down.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?